# Cancel binding depending on object type

Tags: wpf, data-binding

In my WPF application I have a label which is bound to the length of a Text-property:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Editor.Text.Length}"/>
```

The Editor-object may be either a textbox or a checkbox. The textbox does have a Text-property whereas the checkbox does not.
When the Label is bound to a "checkbox-editor" it produces a warning in Visual Studio:

> BindingExpression path error: 'Text' property not found on 'object'...

This is expected and I would like to know if there is any way to tell the binding engine not to try to bind this value unless the Editor-object is a textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the `Editor` property of your viewmodel a control? I hope not, but anyway.

You could write a valueconverter that returns the type of the value, and then set the Label's Content via a series of triggers in a Style. If type of Editor is `{x:Type TextBox}`, set it to the binding you've got above. If it's `{x:Type CheckBox}`, make it `{Binding Editor.IsChecked}'.

XAML

```
<Label>
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger 
                    Binding="{Binding ElementName=Editor, Converter={local:GetTypeConverter}}"
                    Value="{x:Type TextBox}"
                    >
                    <Setter 
                        Property="Content" 
                        Value="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=Editor}" 
                        />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger 
                    Binding="{Binding ElementName=Editor, Converter={local:GetTypeConverter}}"
                    Value="{x:Type CheckBox}"
                    >
                    <Setter 
                        Property="Content" 
                        Value="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Editor}" 
                        />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

C#

```
public class GetTypeConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value?.GetType();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, your viewmodel could have a readonly property which returns whatever should be in that label, since the viewmodel has `Editor` and knows what it is. Call it `EditorLabelValue` for the time being. Presumably `Editor` is bound to a `string` property or a `bool` property, depending on which editor it is. So both of those setters would raise `PropertyChanged` for `"EditorLabelValue"`, which would return the appropriate value.

I tried to do this in pure XAML by making `Editor` the `Content` of a `ContentControl` and then playing with DataTemplates, but I couldn't find a way to make that work without getting an exception for reparenting `Editor`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Great answer. Good idea with the trigger. But as with much in WPF it's a bit lengthy though. I think that I should use a separate property in my viewmodel as you also suggested, that's probably the most clean way to do it.